# How do you change the Gmail logo?

Tags: gmail

I've seen some Gmail accounts that have either a custom image where the gmail logo would be, or, no Gmail logo at all.

Just curious how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google offers [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/) for your domain - a way to use Gmail and other Google applications with your own domain name.  You can customize some of the user interface.

Another option is to run a [userscript or Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/37452) that changes the logo.

Lastly, there are many [skins](http://emailaddresspro.com/gmail-skins/) you can apply that remove or change the logo, and you can write your own skin as well.

Comment: +1 I have Google Apps on my domain, and have a picture of a gnome there instead of the Gmail logo :)

Comment: Thanks. The userscript is pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like the accounts you saw were using [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/gmail.html) with [custom logos](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96474)

Hope this helps.